# Why can't we comment on specific edits?

Tags: feature-request, comments, editing

Why can't we comment on specific edits that are made on different questions or answers?

Comment: What are you asking for, the ability to attach a comment in the edit history?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Yes, so that we can help understand why certain edits were made if the comments given by the editors are insufficient.

Comment: I think you can @ddress comments on the post to the editor even if that editor isn't an author of or commenter on that post.

Comment: For instance: @msh210 did you get this ping?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Not everyone can do pings.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Let's just see if msh210 gets it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I did.

Comment: Bingo!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @IsaacMoses - you are in the Chat currently so I assume that you are online.  Can you tell me if you receive this ping?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, I did, because I commented on this post. Pings through comments on the site work the same for everyone, as do regular pings in chat. The only thing that mods have special is "super pings," whereby we can ping someone from chat even if they haven't been there recently.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can comment on specific edits by commenting on the post itself, @ddressing the editor and including a link to the revision (which you can find by clicking on the chainlink icon next to the revision).

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed one way to do it.